# PHP upgrade from 7.2.0 to 7.2.1

Tags: php, apache, upgrade, php-7.2

I have a directory where is PHP 7.2.0 : C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP 7.2/
Apache was configured to run this version of PHP.

Then, I have created the directory C:/Program Files (x86)/php-7.2.1/ on my system to upgrade to PHP 7.2.1
I changed my Apache 2.4 conf file to :

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/php-7.2.1/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/php-7.2.1/php.ini"
```

Then, when I run phpinfo(); I keep getting :

```
PHP Version 7.2.0
```

But, still, in settings, I can see :

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.2.1\php.ini
```

Any idea on what I am missing ?

Comment: How do you run PHP ?

Comment: For starters, "I have created the directory C:/Program Files (x86)/php-7.2.1/ on my system." says only that you've created a directory, not that you've upgraded anything.

Comment: @Narf I said "upgraded" because it ran with a directory in which I have php 7.2.0 before

Comment: @DanFromGermany Apache runs as a service on Windows

Comment: Where/how are you running phpinfo?

Comment: @Dave I put my phpinfo(); on a web page in D:/www/MyWebSite/ - my Apache DocumentRoot is set as "D:/www/"

Comment: After you made the changes did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes I did. It changes the values in the phpinfo() for Loaded Configuration File from C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP 7.2\php.ini to C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.2.1\php.ini

Comment: How do you run PHP ? Please include that part in your question. Where do you point Apache to the PHP binary. Obvously this points still to 7.2.0.

Comment: The only link I have between PHP and Apache is the instruction LoadModule php7_module "C:\WEB\php-7.2.1\php7apache2_4.dll". I don't see any other instruction where I can tell Apache which binary to use

Comment: Aaah, I didn't read that, sorry. You have restarted Apache right?

Comment: Yes I did. I even restart the whole server...

Comment: Do you run phpinfo() from console or through Apache? It is possible that your console still points to 7.2.0 CLI version and Apache has 7.2.1

Comment: phpinfo() is from Apache... If I run php.exe -v inside a console in my folder, I get 7.2.1...

Comment: Found it! Someone put the php7_apache24.dll file into the Apache/bin folder...